# Force iconic representation except when Flip3D is used

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

In an application of mine, I want to have the Peek preview set to a bitmap that I am generating.

As a result, I call `DwmSetWindowAttribute` to set `DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP` and `DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION` to `TRUE`.

This works, I'm receiving the `WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL` and `WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP` messages just fine.

However, there is one issue when using the Flip3D (Win-Tab) feature in that it's the thumbnail that gets requested, not the live preview.

Not setting `DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION` to `TRUE` means that I don't get the `WM_DWMSENDICONIC` messages, so I can't remove it permanently.

However, if the application is notified when Flip3D is starting/stopping, then I can set `DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION` to `FALSE` and `TRUE` accordingly.

Do you know if and how the application is notified when Flip3D is starting/stopping?

Answer (score 0):

There is no notification of Flip3D activity.  The DWM messages are your only indication.  When dealing with live previews, make sure you are calling `DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps()` whenever your window contents change so that Windows knows it needs to request an updated bitmap from you.